# Why do I no longer receive OutputDataReceived events when restarting a process?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a ChildProcessMonitor class that launches my process, reports data received and restarts the process when it exits.  My problem is that once the process exits and Start is called again, output is no longer reported.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WcfClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Can be used to launch and monitor (restart on crash) the child process.
    /// </summary>
    public class ChildProcessMonitor
    {
        private Process _process;

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts and monitors the child process.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fullProcessPath">The full executable process path.</param>
        public void StartAndMonitor(string fullProcessPath)
        {
            StartAndMonitor(fullProcessPath, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts and monitors the child process.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fullProcessPath">The full executable process path.</param>
        /// <param name="arguments">The process arguments.</param>
        public void StartAndMonitor(string fullProcessPath, string arguments)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = fullProcessPath,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullProcessPath) ?? string.Empty,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            processStartInfo.Arguments = arguments;             

            _process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true };
            _process.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
            _process.ErrorDataReceived += OnErrorDataReceived;
            _process.Start();
            _process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            _process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            _process.Exited += OnProcessExited;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when process exits.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_process != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);                 
                _process.Start();                       
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The ErrorDataReceived event indicates that the associated process has written to its redirected StandardError stream.
        /// </summary>
        public DataReceivedEventHandler ErrorDataReceived;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when error data received.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void OnErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error data.");
            if (ErrorDataReceived != null)
            {
                ErrorDataReceived(sender, e);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The OutputDataReceived event indicates that the associated Process has written to its redirected StandardOutput stream.
        /// </summary>
        public DataReceivedEventHandler OutputDataReceived;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when output data received.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Output data.");
            if (OutputDataReceived != null)
            {
                OutputDataReceived(sender, e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is output the only event that stops working, or do you lose all your events (output, error, exited)?

Comment: I lose output and error, but Exited is fine.

Comment: Your code can't work, you have to call StartAndMonitor() again to restart the process.

Comment: _process.Start() restarts the process.  It's just the output that I'm not receiving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use:

```
private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (_process != null)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    _process.CancelOutputRead();
    _process.CancelErrorRead();
    _process.Start();
    _process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    _process.BeginErrorReadLine();

  }
}
```

**ps**

Short description: OutputRead & ErrorRead closed with process restarting.

Long description with code from reflection:

```
public void BeginOutputRead()
{
  [..]
  if (this.output == null)
  {
    [..]                    
    this.output = new AsyncStreamReader(this, baseStream, new UserCallBack(this.OutputReadNotifyUser), this.standardOutput.CurrentEncoding);
  }
}

public void Start()
{   
    this.Close();
    [..]
}

public void Close()
{   
    [..]
    this.output = null;
    this.error = null;
    [..]
}
```

Comment: Ah ha!  I understand now.  This answers my question but I think I'll use @Malcom O'Hares option 2 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 - Didn't Work**

I would try this edit.  It will refresh the Event Handlers on the object.

```
private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_process != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); 
                _process.OutputDataReceived -= OnOutputDataReceived;
                _process.ErrorDataReceived -= OnErrorDataReceived;
                _process.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
                _process.ErrorDataReceived += OnErrorDataReceived;                
                _process.Start();                       
            }
        }
```

**Option 2**

My next idea would be to suggest a slight design change.  Store the ProcessStartInfo in the class, and then when an exit occurs instead of calling Start on the existing process, dispose it and create a new process using the ProcessStartInfo object.

**Option 3**

After reading the MSDN on the process class, I believe this excerpt explains the issue

> The ErrorDataReceived event indicates that the associated process has
>   written to its redirected StandardError stream.
>
> The event only occurs during asynchronous read operations on
>   StandardError. To start asynchronous read operations, you must
>   redirect the StandardError stream of a Process, **add your event handler
>   to the ErrorDataReceived event, and call BeginErrorReadLine**.
>   Thereafter, the ErrorDataReceived event signals each time the process
>   writes a line to the redirected StandardError stream, until the
>   process exits or calls CancelErrorRead.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx)

So you should just need to do this in your exit handling code

```
    _process.Start();
    _process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    _process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I ended up doing, but it still doesn't answer my question as to why the events are lost in the original scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the update in Option 3, but @DarkGray is right that I need to cancel the outputs first before trying to read again.